# Converting iPhone app to Universal, "File->Create iPad version" not found in XCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.2

I have read all the questions regarding this. They all say I must click on "Create iPad version" or right-click the target and duplicate it. Neither of those to options are in my XCode 4.2?

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your project settings. (cmd+1, then click on your xcodeproj) select one of your targets and select duplicate. When prompted, select the option for covert to iPad.

If there are no options, please post a screen shot of what you do have after you click duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need not create separate target for each device. Instead, you can change the Devices in project summary to Universal which would be in iPhone already. This is answered in the link [Updating iOS 5 App to Universal on Xcode 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910803/updating-ios-5-app-to-universal-on-xcode-4-2/8910910#8910910).