# Updating iOS 5 App to Universal on Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

i am currently developing an App based on **iOS 5 on Xcode 4.2**. which now i have to convert it into a **Universal app**. In Xcode i didn't find **Update Current Target to iPad** but i came to know from stackoverflow that i need to **Duplicate the Target** and select option **Transition to iPad**. which i ended up doing. But now i have two targets and the new target has current device family set to iPad only and not iPhone/iPad. Does this means i have two different builds i.e 2 different apps and not one Universal App.

Should i just choose **current device family** to **iPhone/iPad** in **build settings** instead of duplicating the target or does the two target still implies one Universal App??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a new target for making a universal app. Just delete the new target and then for your original target, go to the target/summary tab and in the Devices dropdown select universal instead of iPhone and it will do the transition for you.